# rust struct with generics compile error

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I wrote following code in rust. version is 0.12.0-pre-nightly.

```
struct Sample<T> {
    x: T
}

impl<T> Sample<T> {
    pub fn new<T>(v: T) -> Sample<T> {
        Sample { x: v }
    }

    pub fn get<T>(&self) -> T {
        self.x
    }
}

fn main() {
    Sample::new(0i).get(); // expect int 0
}
```

and got compile error.

```
hoge.rs:11:9: 11:15 error: mismatched types: expected `T`, found `T` (expected type parameter, found type parameter)
hoge.rs:11         self.x
```

I cannot figure out by compiler message why sample program cannot be compiled.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put type parameters on your methods. They must use the one from the `impl`.

```
struct Sample<T> {
    x: T
}

impl<T> Sample<T> {
    pub fn new(v: T) -> Sample<T> {
        Sample { x: v }
    }

    pub fn get(&self) -> T {
        self.x
    }
}

fn main() {
    Sample::new(0i).get(); // expect int 0
}
```

P.S.: That code doesn't compile either because `get` tries to move `x` out of `&self`. You can change `impl<T>` to `impl<T: Copy>` if you want to use copyable types only, or change `get` to return a reference:

```
    pub fn get(&self) -> &T {
        &self.x
    }
```